Overhead Conveyor System Design for ABS Tubes
I'm working on an overhead conveyor system suspended from the ceiling to carry ABS tubes, and I'd appreciate some feedback and advice to help refine the design. Here's a breakdown of the system specs and the challenges I'm facing:

Load Specifications: Each ABS tube is 3 inches in diameter, 80 inches long, and weighs 8.5 kg. They are spaced with a 2-inch gap between each tube.
Track and Trolley Design: I’ve built a trolley line to carry the tubes, designed to slide along a profile track. The track itself forms a loop approximately 80 feet in length.
Curvature and Friction Challenges: The track includes curved sections, and I need to validate the feasibility of these curves. I’m especially looking for advice on the minimum radius needed to keep friction manageable, as well as considerations for wear and stability during manual or automated operation.
Manual and Automated Operation: The system currently operates manually by pushing or pulling the tubes. Ideally, it should be adaptable for future automation with minimal redesign. I’d love insights on how to design the initial system so that adding automation later (like a motor drive or chain) would be smooth.

Here you can find pictures from the trolley and track: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H_FzNp-rB816JuZVLOqQ3dIw2kiycS07?usp=sharing
**The tubes will be suspended beneath dual-sided wheels, which are part of the trolley system but not designed yet.
I’d appreciate feedback on potential weak points, ways to optimize the manual/automatic design, and any experience with overhead systems handling similar loads.
Thanks in advance for your thoughts and advice!
